Installing and Deploy cmdbuild and OpenMaint for windows 10
How can i install openmaint 2.3 and deploy it with cmdbuild 3.4.3 in windows 10, hope the steps in details.the sever in the browser keep saying application context in path /cmdbuild and /openmaint could not be started.
Am tring to deploy it in Tomcat server
